# A question on double integral

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

Evaluate $\iint\cos(\max\{x^3,y^{3/2}\})\;\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$ over the region $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Since the region is the unit square, the limits of $x$ and $y$ must be constant, both from $0$ to $1$; but what to do with $\max\{x^3,y^{3/2}\}$ in the integrand? However, for any fixed $x$, this maximum value must be $1$ but not sure as I think it must depend on $y$ rather. Any hint, Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to break the square into two (unsquare) regions.  When is $x^3 \geq y^{3/2}$? In the first quadrant, it's when $x\geq \sqrt{y}$ or $y\leq x^2$.
So for the region $D$ inside the square and below the parabola $y=x^2$, the integrand is $\cos(x^3)$.  Above the parabola the integrand is $\cos (y^{3/2})$.

Comment: You meant to say the integrand is $\cos (y^{3/2})$.

Comment: @B.Goddard...Thanks a lot

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks.  Fixed it.